# How to block typing characters and letters into a number-only input in a Vue V-validate form

Tags: vee-validate

How to block typing characters and letters into a number-only input in a Vue V-validate form?, this is the field of the form in question:

Comment: <b-form-input autocomplete="on"  name="Cédula" class="w-100 form-control col-12" v-model="formFields.cedula" v-validate="'required|numeric|min:7|max:10'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('Cédula') }" type="text" placeholder="Cédula" />

Comment: Simply change  `type="text"` to  `type="number"`.

Answer (score -1):

Only change the type="number" so that it does not support typing letters or characters:

...
...